# How to calculate how many tiles you need for a tile-floor in Java

Tags: java

I just recently started programming and ran into this problem.

How do I calculate how many tiles I need for a tile-floor?
The tile is a square with a width of 20, the floor length and width are inputted by the user.

I can calculate how many full tiles I need by using % but once I get to the tile pieces on the side, I'm stuck. Cutting in smaller strips is allowed, you just can't make a mosaic.

I've tried storing the sizes in a list and adding them up to as close as possible to 20. But then I run into things like using a tile for 2 pieces of 8 and using 2 tiles for 2 pieces of 12, while 2 tiles would be enough.

I can't seem to find a way to code that logic in.

```
final int tile = 20;
    double length = Input.readDouble();
    double width = Input.readDouble();

    int completeColumTiles = (int)width/tile;
    int completeRowTiles = (int)length/tile;
    int tilesWithoutRest = completeRowTiles * completeColumTiles;

    double restLength = length%tile;
    double restWidth = width%tile;

    int tilesRest = calculateRest(completeColumTiles, completeRowTiles, restLength, restWidth);
    int tilesWithRest = tilesWithoutRest + tilesRest;

    System.out.println("You need " + tilesWithRest + " tiles.");
```

So basically i need help with the calculateRest

Comment: **Please**, *post* your code. Click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26371604/edit) and add it at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

What about obtaining something like this?

[image]

Basically, assuming `private static final int TILE_DIMENSION = 20;`, you need:

```
private int getTilesCount(final int floorWidth, final int floorHeight) {
    final int horizontalTiles = (floorWidth % TILE_DIMENSION) + ((floorWidth / TILE_DIMENSION) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    final int verticalTiles = (floorHeight % TILE_DIMENSION) + ((floorHeight / TILE_DIMENSION) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    return horizontalTiles * verticalTiles;
}
```

What I'm doing in this method can be simply decomposed as follows:

- counting the number of tiles in each row (`horizontalTiles`),
- counting the number of tiles in each column (`verticalTiles`), and
- returning the product of these two values.

And here's how I'm *counting the number of tiles in each row/column*:

Count the number of tiles that can hold in a single row/column:

```
floorWidth / TILE_DIMENSION
```

And add 1 more tile in case there's some empty space left in that row/column:

```
+ ((floorWidth / TILE_DIMENSION) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

---

As a side note, in case you don't know it yet, the syntax I'm using here (`(evalutaion) ? expression1 : expression2 ;` is called a [Ternary Operator](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018).
It corresponds exactly to doing (in pseudo-code):

```
variable result;
if (evaluation) {
    result = expression1;
} else {
    result = expression2;
}
```

Comment: Thats what I currently have but I need to use the tile pieces on the right and bottom to try and use less tiles. So basically you can use 1 tile for 2 pieces or more, depending how big the pieces on the right and bottom are.

Comment: Oops. Ok. I didn't understand that: my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works: First calculating the uncut blocks, then the side with the largest gap and lastly the side with the smaller gap, trying to reuse the leftover pieces from the first side.

```
int countTiles() {
    int wholeTilesX = roomWidh / 20;
    int wholeTilesY = roomHeight / 20;

    int remainingGapX = roomWidh % 20;
    int remainingGapY = roomHeight % 20;

    int neededExtraTiles;
    if(remainingGapX > remainingGapY) {
        neededExtraTiles = countTilesNeededForSides(
            wholeTilesX, remainingGapX, wholeTilesY, remainingGapY);
    } else {
        neededExtraTiles = countTilesNeededForSides(
            wholeTilesY, remainingGapY, wholeTilesX, remainingGapX);
    }

    int neededTiles = wholeTilesX*wholeTilesY+neededExtraTiles;
    return neededTiles;
}

// Assuming side A has a larger gap.
private int countTilesNeededForSides(
            int wholeTilesSideA, int gapSideA, 
            int wholeTilesSideB, int gapSideB) {

    int gapPiecesB = wholeTilesSideB * 20/gapSideA;
    int leftoversFittingA = wholeTilesSideB * ((20%gapSideA) / gapSideB);

    // +1 is for the corner
    int neededBitsSideA = (wholeTilesSideA+1) - leftoversFittingA;

    int gapPiecesA = neededBitsSideA > 0 ? neededBitsSideA * 20/gapSideA : 0;   
    return gapPiecesA+gapPiecesB;
}
```